# How to turn off Windows computer from Android phone using Python

Tags: android, python, windows, sockets

I'm trying to make an app from my android phone which, when I open it turns off my computer.
From a tutorial I made to file: a server and a client. The server file is running on my pc. And I made an apk from the client file for my phone.
When the server file is running and I open the app on my phone, than nothing happens, nothing. But if I run the client file from my computer, then it turns off.

server.py

```
import socket
import os

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
print(host)
port = 8080
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()

command = os.system("shutdown.exe /s /t 00")
conn.send(command.encode())

data = conn.recv(1024)
```

client.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "ip"
port = 8080
s.connect((host, port))

command = s.recv(1024)
command = command.decode()
```

What could be the problem and how could I solve it?

**Update**

I figured out that I've used the wrong ip address, now I've changed that and it works from a Python Android Ide (QPython3), but it still won't work if I make a .apk file with buildozer, I don't know why

Comment: The problem could be that you are binding to a non-routable address, or your client is trying to connect to an inaccessible address or an address that the server is not bound to, or there is a firewall on your PC blocking connections to your server. And please, use the correct "client/server" terminology to reduce confusion.

Comment: I wrote the wrong ip address in the script and now if I run it from the andriod ide, than it works, but if I make an .apk file than it wont

Comment: And I'll change out the things to client-server, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'v re done the master file to make it simpler and it still works if both of the master and slave files are executed on the computer, but it doesnt work if the slave file is executed on my phone.

```
while True: 
    conn, addr = s.accept() 

    if(conn): 
        command = os.system("shutdown.exe /s /t 200")`
```